# mongo db scheduled backup in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, backup, cron-task

I need to run a scheduled cron task in kubernetes to take mongodb back up and upload it to S3 bucket. 
Looking for a way to do it just via yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use [mgob](https://github.com/stefanprodan/mgob#configure) which provide a yaml file for backup and upload it to S3 Object Storage.Moreover, it bring monitoring as well as notification feature. It can also be deployed on k8s.

A step by step guide on running MGOB as a StatefulSet with PersistentVolumeClaims can be found [here](https://github.com/stefanprodan/mgob/tree/master/k8s)